# How import a external js library in laravel?

Tags: php, node.js, laravel-5

I've downloaded a base template from this [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/puikinsh/gentelella) based on the following dashboard [gentella](https://colorlib.com/polygon/gentelella/tables.html).

I install the [inputmask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) library with the following command:

```
npm install inputmask --save
```

But reading and reading, I'm not sure which is the correct step to integrate the same into an HTML page, I read about `mix`, `saas`, `Compiling Assets (Laravel Mix)`.

I try with this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/inputmaskpath.js') }}"></script>
```

and this:

```
@section('scripts')
    {{ Html::script(mix('assets/js/inputmask.js')) }}
@endsection
```

**The question finally is, how import `inputmask` into my HTML page and what it is the correct path?**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When you use npm to download packages, they will be downloaded in node_modules folder and they are not (directly) included/loaded into your project.

You use Laravel Mix to handle the assets compilation. So in your scenario you could handle it as the following:

First of all create a javascript file in `resources/assets/js` called `app.js`. Add the following code to be able to load the downloaded package

```
require('inputmask');
```

Then using Laravel mix you can compile `app.js` to produce for you one javascript file. Modify `webpack.mix.js` in your Laravel root folder to the following

```
mix.js('./resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js/app.js');
```

Now in your view you could load the javascript file as the following

```
<script src="{!! mix('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
```

So, in case of another downloaded package, you install it with npm first, then in your `resources/assets/js/app.js` file you require that package. Then Laravel mix will take care of combining all required packages into one javascript file.

I suggest you read [this documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mix) for more information about Laravel Mix. [This tutorial](https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-4/episodes/3) is useful also.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this really well, appreciate it.