# Installing and using js-cookie dependency with npm in Laravel

Tags: laravel, npm, dependency-injection, dependencies

I tried installing js-cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) using npm in my Laravel project, but I keep getting the same *ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined* error. It works just fine with a local copy of js-cookie and via CDN, but I would like to figure out why it doesn't work via npm.

**What I've tried:**

```
npm i js-cookie  
npm i js-cookie --save  
npm i js-cookie --save-dev
```

followed by

```
npm run dev
```

**What I get as a result:**
- js-cookie v 2.2.1 gets included in my package.json under dependencies or devDependencies
- js-cookie appears under node_mnodules
- *ReferenceError: Cookies is not defined* while trying to use any Cookies functions

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit 1 - including all my code**
My master.blade.php looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
        <title>@yield('title')</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/nightmode-toggle.css') }}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/nightmode-toggle.js') }}"></script>
    </head>
    <body id="mybody">
        @include('layouts.navbar')
        <div class="content">
            @yield('content')
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The content of the nightmode-toggle.css are just a few classes I toggle on and off while clicking a "Nightmode" checkbox:

```
body.night {
  background:black;
  color:white;
}

.navbar.night {
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
}

etc...
```

The content of nightmode-toggle.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (Cookies.get('nightmode-toggle') != 'on' && Cookies.get('nightmode-toggle') != 'off') {
        Cookies.set('nightmode-toggle', 'off');
    }

    if (Cookies.get('nightmode-toggle') == 'off' && $('body').hasClass('night')) {
        $('body').toggleClass('night');
        $('.navbar').toggleClass('night');
        etc...
    } else if (Cookies.get('nightmode-toggle') == 'on' && !$('body').hasClass('night')) {
        $('body').toggleClass('night');
        $('.navbar').toggleClass('night');
        etc...
    }

    $('#nightmode-toggle').click(function () {
        if (Cookies.get('nightmode-toggle') == 'off') {
            Cookies.set('nightmode-toggle', 'on');
            $('body', ).toggleClass('night');
            $('.navbar').toggleClass('night');
            etc...

        } else {
            Cookies.set('nightmode-toggle', 'off');
            $('body').toggleClass('night');
            $('.navbar').toggleClass('night');
            etc...
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/toggle",

            success: function () {
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('Could not switch to Night Mode for some reason! Please try again later.');
            }
        });
    })
});
```

As I said earlier, if I include a local js-cookie.js file in the header, like so

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/js-cookie.js') }}"></script>
```

or if I include CDN in the header, like so

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@beta/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
```

everything works perfectly fine aka cookies get recorded correctly and classes change depending on the cookie. But I really want to figure out how to include js-cookie using npm as instructed by the developer.

Answer (score 4):

You need to import the library in `bootstrap.js` or `app.js` as an ES6 module as per [the docs](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#es-module)

```js
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'
```

Then use it anywhere else like so

```js
Cookies.set('foo', 'bar')
```

Comment: let's say this is my app.js found under resourses/js:  
`require('./bootstrap');  
window.Vue = require('vue');  
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);  
const app = new Vue({  
    el: '#app',  
});`  
Am i suppose to just shove _import Cookies from 'js-cookie'_ on any line and it is meant to work? Or do you want me to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45125009/how-import-a-external-js-library-in-laravel)?

Comment: Alright, I've inserted it on the first line. Still getting the same ReferenceError. Also when I insert _import Cookies from 'js-cookie'_, _import_ is underlined and it says'Cookies' is declared but its value is never read.

Comment: You're not using it on that file, edit the question and show us the code how you're using it and where

Comment: Sorry for the delay, wasn't home. I have included all the code that is relevant to my question. Also I'd like to add that when I insert _import Cookies from 'js-cookie'_ into my nightmode-toggle.js file, I am given the following error: **SyntaxError: import declarations may only appear at top level of a module**. So yes, you are right, I am suppose to import them either in app.js or bootstrap.js, but I don't know exactly where

Answer (score 2):

If anyone in the future stumbles into this problem.

In resources/js/bootstrap.js file import Cookie as,

```
window.Cookies = require('js-cookie');
```

And you can use 'Cookies' anywhere, eg.

```
    Cookies.set('name', 'value');
```